# Sentinel program isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner, and I need some help with my assignment. I can't work out what I've done wrong.

I have to make a program to read a collection of exam scores ranging in value from 0 to 100 and -1 to stop processing. Input and validate the score. The program should count and print the number of passes (>=50) and the number of fails (0-50). When a score of -1 is entered, the number of passes and the number of fails are displayed.

```
<script>
var score = 0;
var passCount = 0;
var failCount = 0;

score = parseInt(prompt("Input score between 1-100, -1 to quit","0"));

while (score !< 0){
    if (score >= 50 || score <= 100){
    passCount = passCount + 1;
    alert ("You passed! Pass count = "+passCount+"Fail count = "+failCount);
    }
    else
    if (score<50){
    failCount = failCount + 1;
    alert ("You failed! Pass count = "+passCount+"Fail count = "+failCount);
    }
    else
    if (score > 100){
    alert ("Invalid number");
    }
    score = parseInt(prompt("Input score between 1-100, -1 to quit","0"));
}
document.write ("Total: Passes - "+passCount+"Fails "+failCount);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes to be done:**

1. `while (score >= 0)`

   There is no operator `!<`. You either have to use `while (! (score<0))` or `while (score >=0)` or `while (score != -1)`
2. if (score >= 50 `&&` score <= 100)

   Since you are using `||` `OR` operator in original code, the control never goes to the failCount branch. Need to use `AND` operator for the condition to be valid.

**Final code:**

```
<script>
var score = 0;
var passCount = 0;
var failCount = 0;

score = parseInt(prompt("Input score between 1-100, -1 to quit","0"));

while (score >= 0){
    if (score >= 50 && score <= 100){
    passCount = passCount + 1;
    alert ("You passed! Pass count = "+passCount+"Fail count = "+failCount);
    }
    else
    if (score<50){
    failCount = failCount + 1;
    alert ("You failed! Pass count = "+passCount+"Fail count = "+failCount);
    }
    else
    if (score > 100){
    alert ("Invalid number");
    }
    score = parseInt(prompt("Input score between 1-100, -1 to quit","0"));
}
document.write ("Total: Passes - "+passCount+"Fails "+failCount);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your condition `while(score != -1)`